# Calculus - Maximum volume equation

Tags: calculus

I tried my best to come up with an answer but I failed. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this:

> Question: To carry a suitcase on an airplace, the length + width + height must be less than or equal to $ 62$ in. Assuming that height is fixed, show that the maximum volume is $ V = h(31-\frac{1}{2}h)^2 .$

Based on that, I did the following:
$$l+w+h = 62$$
$$l+w = 62 - h$$

$$V = lwh$$
$$dV = dl(lwh) + dw(lwh) +dh(lwh)$$
$$dV = wh + lh + 0$$
$$dV = h(l+w)$$
$$dV = h(62-h)$$

I dont know what else to do after this...Any suggestions recommendation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to express the volume as a function of a single variable.  Since $h$ is a constant, that variable can be either $l$ or $w$.  Let's use $w$.

We are given that $l + w + h = 62~\text{in}$.  Hence, $l = 62~\text{in} - h - w$.  Substituting $62~\text{in} - h - w$ for $l$ in the equation $V = lwh$ yields
$$V(w) = (62~\text{in} - h - w)wh = (62~\text{in})wh - wh^2 - w^2h$$
Differentiating with respect to $w$, while remembering that $h$ is a constant, yields
$$V'(w) = (62~\text{in})h - h^2 - 2wh$$
Setting the derivative equal to $0$ and solving for $w$ yields
$$w = 31~\text{in} - \frac{h}{2}$$
Since $h > 0$,
$$V''(w) = -2h < 0$$
Thus, the function has a relative maximum at $w = 31~\text{in} - \dfrac{h}{2}$ by the [Second Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second_derivative_test_(single_variable)).

When $w = 31~\text{in} - \dfrac{h}{2}$, then 
$$l = 62~\text{in} - h - w = 62~\text{in} - h - \left(31~\text{in} - \frac{h}{2}\right) = 31~\text{in} - \frac{h}{2}$$
Thus, the maximum volume of the suitcase is 
$$V = lwh = \left(31~\text{in} - \frac{h}{2}\right)\left(31~\text{in} - \frac{h}{2}\right)h = \left(31~\text{in} - \frac{h}{2}\right)^2h$$

Answer (score 1):

$$l+w+h=62$$
Therefore, $L+w=62-h$.  In order to maximise the volume, the area enclosed by the rectangle, $l\times w$ should be maximum and thus, $l=w$.  Therefore we may write: $2w=62-h$, or, $w=31-\frac1 2 h$.  Now substitute this in the equation for total volume, $V=lwh=(31-\frac 1 2 h)^2h$.

QED.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$ l+w+h = 62$

$l+w = 62-h$

$(l^2+w^2)(1^2+1^2) \geq (l+w)^2$

$2(l^2+w^2) \geq (l+w)^2$

$2((l+w)^2-2lw) \geq (l+w)^2$

$2(l+w)^2-4lw \geq (l+w)^2$

$(l+w)^2 \geq 4lw$

since $ lw = \frac{V}{h} $

$(62-h)^2 \geq \frac{4V}{h}$

$h(62-h)^2 \geq 4V$

$ V \leq h(31-\frac{1}{2}h)^2$

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

> To maximise the volume at fixed height you have to maximise the section of the suitcase. In this case it has to be either rectangular of square: in any case you can construct a square with the same area as a rectangle. Square section is very much easier to work with.

### Solution

> To maximise the volume with a fixed height you have to maximise the section of the suitcase. In the simplest case, because it doesn't really matters, you can choose a square section so that $w=l$. In this case you have $$2w = 62-h\\w = 31-{1\over 2}h$$ the area of a square is $$S = w^2 = (31-{1\over 2}h)^2$$ In the end, the maximum volume is $$V=hS = h(31-{1\over 2}h)^2$$